# articles about fonts in linux or fonts in general

Tags: linux, fonts

I have heard some terms about linux fonts,such as XFT, fontconfig etc.I just cann't figure out these mumble jumbo.Is there any good tutorial/article about fonts in linux?or fonts in general in the computer science.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XFT is the X FreeType (TrueType clone/compatible) Font rasterization library (It draws font). FreeType fonts are just like TrueType (ttf). Fontconfig is a library for global font configuration.  Font is really simple, just think of it as stamps. Read about rasterization and you'll understand better how font works.

Comment: xft was a first attempt to modernize xfree86 font rendering, it was quickly superseeded by client-side fonts (fontconfig) which has been the norm since the mid '00.

Answer (score 0):

- [Fonts in X11R7.6](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/fonts/fonts.html)
- [Optimal Use of Fonts on Linux (Font-HOWTO)](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Font-HOWTO/)
- [Frequently Asked Questions About Fonts: The comp.fonts FAQ, Version 2.1.5., August 14, 1996](http://nwalsh.com/comp.fonts/FAQ/index.html) *(though it's 15 years out of date now, a lot of the basic underlying technology is still the same - TrueType has mostly supplanted Postscript/Type1)*

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
http://behdad.org/text/ (a bit dated)

Long answer: read text layout presentations and the mailing lists they link to
on [freedesktop.org/wiki/TextLayout/](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/TextLayout/)
starting from
http://www.unifont.org/textlayout/TheBigPicture.pdf

Then you can read [planet.open-fonts.org](http://planet.open-fonts.org)